# How can one test a neural network against new data in MatLab?

Tags: neural-networks, matlab, data-mining, prediction

I am new with MatLab and NN. I used the Neural Network Time Series Tool (https://nl.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/neural-network-time-series-prediction-and-modeling.html) in order to a make prediction and at the end it offers the possibility to test the NN against new data (for example the actual observations to predict). Then, you can also have the script of what you have done but it does not include the code about testing the NN against new data.
What is the code for that please? This is the MatLab code using the given data

```
% Bayesian regularization backpropagation

% Create a Nonlinear Autoregressive Network
feedbackDelays = 1:7;
hiddenLayerSize = 12;
net = narnet(feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize,'open','trainbr');

% Removing inputs/targets that are constant and normalizing inputs/targets to fall in the range [?1, 1] 
net.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

% Prepare the Time Series Data for Training and Simulation
[x,xi,ai,t] = preparets(net,{},{},T);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'time';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Performance Function
net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean Squared Error

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t,xi,ai);

% Test the Network
y = net(x,xi,ai);
e = gsubtract(t,y);
performance = perform(net,t,y)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = gmultiply(t,tr.trainMask);
valTargets = gmultiply(t,tr.valMask);
testTargets = gmultiply(t,tr.testMask);
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,y)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,y)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,y)

% Closed Loop Network
netc = closeloop(net);
netc.name = [net.name ' - Closed Loop'];
[xc,xic,aic,tc] = preparets(netc,{},{},T);
yc = netc(xc,xic,aic);
closedLoopPerformance = perform(net,tc,yc)


% Multi-step Prediction
[x1,xio,aio,t] = preparets(net,{},{},T);
[y1,xfo,afo] = net(x1,xio,aio);
[netc,xic,aic] = closeloop(net,xfo,afo);
[y2,xfc,afc] = netc(cell(0:100),xic,aic);


% % Step-Ahead Prediction Network
nets = removedelay(net);
nets.name = [net.name ' - Predict One Step Ahead'];
[xs,xis,ais,ts] = preparets(nets,{},{},T);
ys = nets(xs,xis,ais);
stepAheadPerformance = perform(nets,ts,ys)

figure;
plot([cell2mat(targetSeries),nan(1,N);
      nan(1,length(targetSeries)),cell2mat(yPred);
      nan(1,length(targetSeries)),cell2mat(targetSeriesVal)]')
```

This works well, but I would like to test the NN against new data.

Comment: Do you have a `net` object?

Comment: Yes, I have. Considering the data given and loaded, one has ... look at the question again!

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE! We like to discuss statistics and machine learning, but questions primarily about programming are off topic. The help center has some information about writing good questions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing your NN against new data you have to prepare your data and apply the NN:

```
% get new input data
T = tonndata(target,false,false);

% scale down data and prepare for usage
[x,xi,ai,t] = preparets(net,{},{},T);

% apply net and generate output
y = net(x,xi,ai);

% calculate performance
performance = perform(net,t,y)
```